# Duplicate class found error while using two itextpdf-7 dependencies

Tags: android, itext

I want implement itextpdf-7 in my android project.

When i add only one dependence implementation `'com.itextpdf.android:kernel-android:7.2.2'` I don't have access to some classes like Document, Paragraph, etc.
So I did some reading and I discovered that I have to add `implementation 'com.itextpdf:itext7-core:7.0.2'`

After adding it, i have access to to the classes but now it seems there are duplicate classes  as shown in the error message below:

```
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.codec.BitFile found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.codec.CCITTG4Encoder found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.codec.Jbig2SegmentReader found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.codec.Jbig2SegmentReader$Jbig2Page found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.codec.Jbig2SegmentReader$Jbig2Segment found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.codec.LZWCompressor found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.codec.LZWStringTable found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.codec.PngWriter found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.codec.TIFFConstants found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.codec.TIFFDirectory found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.codec.TIFFFaxDecoder found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.codec.TIFFFaxDecompressor found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.codec.TIFFField found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.codec.TIFFLZWDecoder found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.codec.TiffWriter found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.codec.TiffWriter$FieldAscii found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.codec.TiffWriter$FieldBase found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.codec.TiffWriter$FieldByte found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.codec.TiffWriter$FieldImage found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.codec.TiffWriter$FieldLong found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.codec.TiffWriter$FieldRational found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.codec.TiffWriter$FieldShort found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.codec.TiffWriter$FieldUndefined found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.AdobeGlyphList found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.CFFFont found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.CFFFont$DictNumberItem found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.CFFFont$DictOffsetItem found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.CFFFont$Font found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.CFFFont$IndexBaseItem found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.CFFFont$IndexMarkerItem found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.CFFFont$IndexOffsetItem found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.CFFFont$Item found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.CFFFont$MarkerItem found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.CFFFont$OffsetItem found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.CFFFont$RangeItem found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.CFFFont$StringItem found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.CFFFont$SubrMarkerItem found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.CFFFont$UInt16Item found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.CFFFont$UInt24Item found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.CFFFont$UInt32Item found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.CFFFont$UInt8Item found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.CFFFontSubset found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.CMapEncoding found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.CidFont found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.CidFontProperties found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.FontCache found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.FontCacheKey found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.FontCacheKey$FontCacheBytesKey found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.FontCacheKey$FontCacheStringKey found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.FontCacheKey$FontCacheTtcKey found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.FontEncoding found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.FontIdentification found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.FontMetrics found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.FontNames found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.FontProgram found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.FontProgramDescriptor found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.FontProgramDescriptorFactory found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.FontProgramFactory found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.FontRegisterProvider found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.IExtraEncoding found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.OpenTypeParser found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.OpenTypeParser$CmapTable found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.OpenTypeParser$HeaderTable found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.OpenTypeParser$HorizontalHeader found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.OpenTypeParser$PostTable found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.OpenTypeParser$WindowsMetrics found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.PdfEncodings found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.PdfEncodings$1 found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.PdfEncodings$Cp437Conversion found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.PdfEncodings$SymbolConversion found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
Duplicate class com.itextpdf.io.font.PdfEncodings$SymbolTTConversion found in modules jetified-io-7.0.2 (com.itextpdf:io:7.0.2) and jetified-io-android-7.2 (com.itextpdf.android:io-android:7.2.2)
```

The errors are very many!
How do i resolve them?

Comment: you should use itext7-core-android. So: com.itextpdf.android:itext7-core-android:7.2.2 (just add -android to any module you require). You can see all the modules here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf.android